# Trying elementary OS without installing options get stuck in black screen dual boot Win 10

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I'm trying to install elementary OS on a Lenovo IdeaPad 330S

I did follow the steps for Ubuntu:

- Removing the fast boot option from windows 10
- Disable the boot secure

then when booting from the USB and trying the option to Run or Install it gets stuck in a black screen.
I try changing the parameter [quiet splash] to [nomodeset] but nothing happens.

I'm really lost here.

Thanks in advance for your time, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable secure boot in bios
2. When creating bootable USB use Rufus and GPT partion and Uefi mode in bios
   Now it will work

Comment: I did try it but it did not work, i could open the boot menu and try selecting other options like Nomodeset and it shows a Kernel Panic error [Remapped IO-APIC] then tried nolapic and it again a Kener Panic error, for what i've been reading is my Mother board so i will try with Fedora stead, i will share my situation after that.

Comment: I try with Fedora but it gets stuck in a black screen with a single underscore white char.